# prolog outcome of a loop

Tags: prolog

Hy i'm trying to build this recursive rule in prolog. The problem is this:
I have a tree and i want to cut the tree using some queries. The rule is this:

```
infer(Q):-
   L_new=[],
   cut_the_tree(Q,L_new,Class). 

cut_the_tree(Q,L_new,Class):-

   write('Define the property:'),
   tab(3),
   read(Prop),
   write('Define the object:'),
   tab(3),
   read(Ob),
   Var='http://www.semanticweb.org/marcello/ontologies/2015/7/Inference.owl#',
   atom_concat(Var,Prop,X),
   atom_concat(Var,Ob,Y),
   ((Prop='has',findall(C,class_properties(Y,'http://www.semanticweb.org/marcello/ontologies/2015/7/Inference.owl#physicalPartOf',C),L));(Prop='madeBy',findall(C,class_properties(Y,'http://www.semanticweb.org/marcello/ontologies/2015/7/Inference.owl#materialOf',C),L))),
   test(L,L_new,K),
   write(K),nl,
   length(K,N),
   ((N=1,nth0(0,K,Class));(N>1,write('Non-Unique Solution'),tab(2),write('Assert Manually==1 Or Assert a new property==2:'),tab(2),read(W),case(K,W,Class))),
   write('Define the name of the unknown object:'),
   tab(3),
   read(Z),
   rdf_costom_instance_from_class(Class,_,Z,Q).


case(K,W,Class):-
((W=1),write('Connect to:'),tab(2),read(V),nth0(V,K,Class)).
case(K,W,Class):-
((W=2),L_new=K,cut_the_tree(Q,L_new,Class)).

inter([], _, []).
inter([H1|T1], L2, [H1|Res]) :-
member(H1, L2),
inter(T1, L2, Res).
inter([_|T1], L2, Res) :-
    inter(T1, L2, Res).

test(L,L_new,K):-((length(L_new,J),J\=0,inter(L,L_new,K),!);K=L).
```

When i run the rule i start asking for a property and the system gives me an output checking wich elements has this physical property.After if i don't have a unique solution i can either cut the tree maually or send a new property and the system will check this property on the remaining tree.
The problem is that with this recursive rule the last four lines are repeated in the same number of the rule repetition.
This is what happens on the terminal:

```
?- infer(Q).
Define the property:   'has'.
Define the object:   'Handle'.
[http://www.semanticweb.org/marcello/ontologies/2015/7/Inference.owl#KitchenUtensil,http://www.semanticweb.org/marcello/ontologies/2015/7/Inference.owl#CleaningDevice]
Non-Unique Solution  Assert Manually==1 Or Assert a new property==2:  2.
Define the property:   'madeBy'.
Define the object:   'Plastic'.
[http://www.semanticweb.org/marcello/ontologies/2015/7/Inference.owl#CleaningDevice]
Define the name of the unknown object:   'Broom'.
Define the name of the unknown object:   'BR'.
Q = 'http://www.semanticweb.org/marcello/ontologies/2015/7/Inference.owl#BR' ;
```

Comment: You have virtually no chance to get through this code as long as you are mixing procedural I/O part and the actual logic behind.  So, first start with the pure part **alone**.

Comment: do your prolog has [library(xpath)](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=xpath) ? much easier...

Comment: What @false is probably trying to say, the Prolog top level (the REPL where you write your queries and get solutions) already does the reading and writing for you: no need for `write` and `tab` etc, and you can directly write your user input into the query, so no need for `read`, either. This will already get rid of about half the code you have there.

Comment: yes you're right,but i prefer this way ;)
@CapelliC i don't think so.